# My gulp.js file is only running the first time and then it won't watch

Tags: reactjs, gulp, gulp-watch

I made a `gulp.js` file that is meant to be observing my changes and rebuilding so that my react code can update after the scss gets converted to css with each change. Here's what I have:

```
'use strict';

//dependencies
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var minifyCSS = require('gulp-clean-css');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var changed = require('gulp-changed');


//////////////
// - SCSS/CSS
//////////////

var SCSS_SRC = './src/assets/scss/**/*.scss';
var SCSS_DEST = './src/assets/css';

// Compile SCSS
gulp.task('compile_scss', function(){
  gulp.src(SCSS_SRC)
  .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
  .pipe(minifyCSS())
  .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min'}))
  .pipe(changed(SCSS_DEST))
  .pipe(gulp.dest(SCSS_DEST));
});

//detect changes in SCSS
gulp.task('watch_scss', function(){
  gulp.watch(SCSS_SRC, gulp.series('compile_scss'));
});

//Run tasks
gulp.task('default', gulp.series(['watch_scss'], function(){

}));
```

This is the first time I do this but from what I can tell it is correct. There's no error being thrown and it works sometimes. However, when I make 2 changes to my default.scss file, the 1st one gets converted to css but for the second one I need kill the task and run `gulp` again. What might I be missing?

Comment: Try `return gulp.src.....` in your `compile_scss` task.

Comment: @Mark after the last `.pipe()`?

Comment: No, add the `return` keyword right before `gulp.src...etc.` in the second line.